# How to add data in newly added row in ipysheet?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

When I click on add row button Iam able to add new row but how to add data to that new row, Iam using data frames here ?
Please find the executable code

```
import qgrid,ipysheet
from ipywidgets import widgets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#qgrid.show_grid(df,show_toolbar=True)

random_data = [['ABC','DEF','GHI'],
 [0.69494459,0.90502388,0.13374771],
 [0.89609645,0.66166011,0.12123602],
 [0.51229257,0.57240808,0.25482961],
 [0.25478973,0.08438657,0.76977642]]

df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])  
sheet = ipysheet.from_dataframe(df)
btn = wg.Button(description = 'Add Row')    
def on_bttn_clicked(b):  
    sheet.rows += 1

btn.on_click(on_bttn_clicked)

display(btn,sheet)
```

Comment: Did you find the way?