# How to add column names to ipysheet without using pandas data frame?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipython, ipywidgets

Here we are getting by default A,B as column names, how to override column names and write our own column names

```
import ipysheet
from ipysheet import sheet, cell
sheet1 = sheet()
cell(0,0,10);
cell(1,1,100);
cell(2,2,1000);
cell(3,3,"Hello");
sheet1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own column names for a sheet when you are creating it. You can use the `column_headers` argument for this.

In your case:

```
import ipysheet
from ipysheet import sheet, cell
sheet1 = sheet(column_headers=["Not A", "Not B"])
cell(0,0,10);
cell(1,1,100);
cell(2,2,1000);
cell(3,3,"Hello");
sheet1
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do that.  ipysheet isn't a pandas replacement, it's a spreadsheet package designed to run in jupyter.  Just like a real spreadsheet, you can't change the column headings *because this is how you reference things*.  However, like in a real spreadsheet, you *can* put a heading in the *cell* at the top of a column.  And you can even make it stand out as a 'heading'.

If you don't want to *display* your data in a jupyter notebook you probably don't want ipysheet.

### References

https://github.com/QuantStack/ipysheet

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if so, can you please answer this question if possible (I tried to add columns names using DataFrame but unable to add new row with data ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253919/how-to-add-data-in-newly-added-row-in-ipysheet